# Is it possible to get all the video ids of a youtube playlist when there are more than 100,000 videos in the list?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, playlist

For a youtube playlist with more than 100,000 videos (e.g. the playlist id UUHTK-2W11Vh1V4uwofOfR4w has more than 450,000 videos), it seems that it is only possible to get the video ids for up to 100,000 videos using the url below (pagetoken used below CJ-NBhAA is for the 100,000 videos based on https://github.com/Quihico/handy.stuff/blob/master/yt.pagetokens). The response only has prevPageToken but not the nextPageToken. So is it possible to get all the video ids for the playlist?

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUHTK-2W11Vh1V4uwofOfR4w&maxResults=50&pageToken=CJ-NBhAA&key=[your api key].

Comment: In case of such a huge playlist, one will surely hit it's quota limit anyway.

Comment: @stvar But what if I want to wait or have a way of overcoming the quota limit, is it possible?

Comment: As far as I know. there is no place in the docs where Google puts forward an *algorithm* for generating page tokens by themselves. Neither the doc specifies randomly accessing the set of pages of any given endpoint's result set. For extending default quota limits one has to contact Google [directly](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/).